# Meteor-React tutorial: missing step to install Babel package

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm following the official [Todo App with React tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components). If I follow the steps exactly, after step 2.5, I get an error:

```
=> Exited with code: 1

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" in
/.../todos/imports/ui/App.js (web.browser.legacy)
  "@babel/runtime/helpers/inheritsLoose" in
/.../todos/imports/ui/App.js (web.browser.legacy)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
```

It seems that the current versions of Meteor and the React npm package do not automatically install Babel, so JSX code is not converted to JS.

It would make life easier for others who want to follow this tutorial if the commands ...

```
meteor npm install --save react react-dom
meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
```

... were given together.

Comment: If you have already solved this, would you please open an issue on the todo app repository and tell MDG about this?